# get index of the closed frame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I keep all JInternalFrames in arraylist

```
 ArrayList<JInternalFrame> arr;
```

so every frame have its index.
Every frame contains JScrollPane. MyJPanel(extends JPanel) keep index of the frame.

```
JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame("Frame "+Integer.toString(count),true,true,true,true);
MyJPanel panel = new MyJPanel(f.getAbsolutePath(),count);
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(theDesktop.getWidth()/2,theDesktop.getHeight()/2));
frame.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
```

How to get index of closed JInternalFrame and delete this frame from arraylist?Override some close method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the default close operation for your internal frames and then when you are closing the view call [doDefaultCloseAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#doDefaultCloseAction%28%29) which fires an Event.

Before this add yourself as the listener for this event, upon receipt of event do the necessary action.